# Conditional logic in a pre-build event in Visual Studio returning a 255

Tags: visual-studio, conditional-statements

I've been narrowing down an error I'm getting trying to do a file copy in a pre-build event in Visual Studio. The error is "exited with code 255" which doesn't help me figure out why this syntax is not working:

```
if  '$(PlatformName)' == 'x86' 
  copy C:\work\test\libnria.dll c:\work
```

Does anyone see anything wrong with this? The copy command I've stripped down to a hard-coded example.

Comment: can't advise on the 255 error, but are you sure about `PlatformName` here? Rather than e.g. `PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE` or `PlatformShortName`?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the quotes from around the $(PlatformName) macro?